# Unable to start activity android.view.InflateException: Binary XML line ~1

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created an android application that takes some input from one activity and prints it in the next activity. The app crashes when it tries to go to the next activity. The problem is in the XML but I can't figure out where.

The final Activity:

```
package com.example.competitionapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConfirmationActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        TextView textViewName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLabelName);
        TextView textViewSurname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLabelSurname);


        if(extras !=null) {
            String nameValue = extras.getString("name");
            String surnameValue = extras.getString("surname");


            textViewName.setText(nameValue);
            textViewSurname.setText(surnameValue);
    }


}
}
```

this is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="@string/thanks"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:text="@string/gl"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLabelName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLabelSurname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewLabelName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabelName"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

and my log cat:

```
   10-24 08:50:01.823: E/AndroidRuntime(840): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   10-24 08:50:01.823: E/AndroidRuntime(840): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.example.competitionapp/com.example.competitionapp.ConfirmationActivity}:
   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: It is my first posting. I hope it's understandable

Comment: I would first try cleaning your project. "Project --> Clean..."

Comment: I cleaned the project and the same error is occurring.

Comment: What is drawable bg2? Maybe drawable problem, could you remove and test your app?

Comment: I tried this already. It's just the background and when it's removed the error still occurs.

Comment: I tried it again and it worked. Thank you. I never would have double checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change:

tools:context=".MainActivity"

to

tools:context=".ConfirmationActivity"